# checking data type in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program in VBA in which I'd like the user to only enter a number.  I want to be able to catch when they they enter a string and have them try again.  This is what I've tried:

```
Sub getInterest()
    annualInterest = InputBox("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal. ")
        If TypeOf annualInterest Is Double Then
            'Continue with program
        Else
            Call getInterest()  
        End If
End Sub
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: use isnumeric .

Answer (score 5):

IsNumeric returns a boolean & doesn't tell you what the type of data user entered, only if it passed or failed numeric check. And while it may work in your case another option is VarType function.

[VarType function returns an Integer indicating the subtype of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)

```
Sub getInterest()
    annualinterest = InputBox("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal. ")
        If VarType(annualinterest) = vbDouble OR VarType(annualinterest)=vbSingle Then
            'crunch interest
        Else
            getInterest
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this...

```
Sub getInterest()
Dim annualInterest As Double

Do While annualInterest = 0
    annualInterest = Application.InputBox("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal.", "Annual Interest Rate!", Type:=1)
Loop
MsgBox annualInterest
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax in second row is wrong. please try below code. Code will proceed only if user input is a valid number.

```
Sub getInterest()
    annualinterest = InputBox("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal. ")
        If IsNumeric(annualinterest) Then
            'Continue with program
        Else
            Call getInterest
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simply force a numeric entry in Excel VBA by using the existing parameters.

`annualInterest = Application.InputBox("Please enter your annual interest rate as a decimal. ", , , , , , , 1)`

It will ensure a valid numeric entry and can save the call.